# Android Studio automatic scroll to bottom when ScrollView expands?

Tags: android

Is it possible to make my `ScrollView` automaically scroll to the bottom if the height expands? For example, if a `Checkbox` is checked and some views are then added to the `ScrollView`, they will be "below the current focus" and it might appear as if they were not added.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For automatically scrolling to add the code:

```
final ScrollView scrollview = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview));
scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I just have to do this once or everytime I add views?

Comment: Yes, every time when get focus your scrollview. If you wanna automatically, you need create cycle thread.

Answer (score 2):

```
Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    };
    scrollView.post(runnable);
```

call this lines every time after adding your view to your layout.
That will lead you to initialize Runnable object once.